# Pyspark: Joining with part of key

Tags: pyspark, inner-join

I have two dataframes I want to 'inner' join where the keys are not the same, but when I drop the last character of dataframe 1, the keys are the same.

Example:
Dataframe 1

```
Key             Count
ToyotaA         100
ToyotaB         200
AudiA           300
AudiB           400
```

Dataframe 2

```
Key             Count
Toyota          300
Audi            700
```

I would like to make a join similar to below, which is not working for the moment:

```
TopSales.join(TopSales2, ((TopSales.TIRESIZE[:-1]) == TopSales2.TIRESIZE2, 'inner')).show()
```

Any ideas welcome !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Array slicing `[:-1]` does not work in PySpark and returns an empty string. Below I have included two possible workarounds for this.

If you are happy to use SparkSQL you can write your join in SQL:

```
df1 = sc.parallelize([('ToyotaA',100),('ToyotaB',200),('AudiA',300),('AudiB',400)]).toDF(['Key','Count'])    
sqlContext.registerDataFrameAsTable(df1, "df1")
df2 = sc.parallelize([('Toyota',300),('Audi',700)]).toDF(['Key','Count'])
sqlContext.registerDataFrameAsTable(df2, "df2")
df_combined = sqlContext.sql("select df1.Key,df2.Key,df1.Count,df2.Count from df1 df1 inner join df2 df2 on substring(df1.Key, 0, LENGTH(df1.Key) -1 ) = df2.Key")
df_combined.show()
```

Alternatively, you can add a new column to the first data frame containing the cleaned key:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

substring_udf = udf(lambda value: value[:-1], StringType())
df1=df1.withColumn("cleaned_key", substring_udf(df1.Key))
df1.join(df2, df1.cleaned_key == df2.Key, 'inner').show()
```

The neatest solution would of course be to use the udf inside the join, however, that is not yet supported by PySpark at the time of writing this post.

Comment: Thank you Jaco, the PySpark function worked. Thank you for confirmation that functions needed are not yet supported by Spark at the moment.